# How to change tag based on metabox value within $wp_query

Tags: wp-query

I have a custom post type called "issue" and a contents page for each issue. I tag all of my articles with each issue by the issue number, so for instance, all articles with Issue 15 are tagged `'issue-15'`.

I have a custom post template for contents and I use the following code to call up all issue posts within the same issue number.

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'issue',
    'tag' => 'issue-14',
    'posts_per_page' => 50
) );
```

Where it says `'issue-14'`, I need that to change based on a custom  metabox field called `'issue-number'` which only contains the number of the issue.  So if the metabox field is "`12`" I need the tag to be "`issue-12`".

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're just looking for [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta). Using your [custom field](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) of `issue_number`, you'll do something like this (untested):

```
$issue_number = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'issue_number', true );
$my_issue_query = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'issue',
'tag' => 'issue-' . $issue_number,
'posts_per_page' => 50
));
```

*Note: While the code you pasted may work, you don't want to override the `$wp_query` global with a new `WP_Query` instance. Rather, use a new prefixed query-specific variable to hold the query instead and then call it like `$my_issue_query->the_post();`*